# How do I replace table cell values from a dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I need to "massage" a HTML table.

On the page there is a dropdown:

```
<SELECT CLASS='slctor' size='1' NAME='KEYVAL' ID='KEYVAL' >
                  <OPTION VALUE='{*}'>*
                  </OPTION>
                  <OPTION value='10'>green
                  </OPTION>
                  <OPTION value='20'>green
                  </OPTION>
                  <OPTION value='30'>green
                  </OPTION>
                  <OPTION value='40'>yellow
                  </OPTION>
                  <OPTION value='90'>red
                  </OPTION>
                </SELECT>
```

I also have a table with Person/year and a value for each pair:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>2001</td>
  <td>2002</td>
  <td>2003</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>JOE</td>
  <td>10</td>
  <td>30</td>
  <td>90</td>
</tr><tr>
  <td>BETTY</td>
  <td>20</td>
  <td>20</td>
  <td>40</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want to use jQuery to "resolve" each cell value from the dropdowns value, return the label, and replace the cell content (or the background color).

I am able to do the basics, as in the actual DOM manipulation, but I need help actually doing the lookup in a efficient manner.

Comment: That's a very odd way to use a dropdown. Why would you have multiple values for 'green' for example? It almost looks like you're using it to store variable values.

Comment: I agree, and my example is simplyfied. But this is the way I can currently pull the information from the database, so you are right that the dropdown is just there to provide variables

Comment: Well I'm not sure how you're creating that dropdown, but whatever is creating it should probably just be making a string in a `<script>` tag along the lines of `var green = 30, yellow = 40, red = 90` then you could just use the global variables easily within your script rather than looking them up from the dropdown box.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:

$(".slctor").change(function(){
    var selectedVal=$(this).val();
    $('table').find('td').filter(function(){return $(this).text() ==selectedVal}).css("background-color","red");
   //or
      $('table').find('td').filter(function(){return $(this).text() ==selectedVal}).text("New Text");
});
```

Comment: Thanks - This looks like it will act when the dropdown is touched. I need all values in the table replaced, and already have a "loop" where I have a value (20) and I just need to "ask" the dropdown the label of value "20".

Comment: '$("table#DASPIVOT tr td a").each(function (i) {
        if (this.text == "0") {
    this.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
    this.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
        } else {
  var tcolor = 0;
  var tcust = 0;
  var tstr = this.innerHTML.replace(".","");
  var tln = tstr.length;
   if (tln == 6){
   tcolor = tstr.slice(4,6);
   tcust = tstr.slice(0,4)
   }
   else{
   tcolor = tstr.slice(0,2);
   tcust = 0;
   this.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
   }
  console.log(tcolor + '//' + tcust);
  this.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
      });
});'

Comment: oh this looks awful.. sorry. In my real case, cells have a value of eg. 103080 - which means customer 1030, classification 80. it's the last two digits of the value I need to resolve on.

Comment: Basically, I can solve my problem if I can write a function getFromDD(val,ddname) that can return "green" if I pass (20, 'KEYVAL') as parameters